# UITextView Line Numbering

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add line numbers to a UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836162/how-to-add-line-numbers-to-a-uitextview)

I am trying to create a simple code editor view on iOS. I have seen many apps that have line numbering on the left side of the view. I am at a loss on how to implement this. Is it a separate view that is maintained when the code editor view is change? Or possibly custom drawing done is drawRect:? Some guidance would be very appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836162/how-to-add-line-numbers-to-a-uitextview

:)

Comment: Thanks! I've seen that solution and it seems like my best bet.