# How to add line numbers to UITextView in Swift (structure of app built using SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, uitextview

I am making a code editor for iPad (as a fun little project). I am trying to add line numbers to a UITextView that is in the SwiftUI code via a UIViewRepresentable. Any ideas on how to go about this? I should mention, I use an NSAttributedString for syntax hilighting. Here is a paired down version of my code (to fit better).

**The view that references the UITextView**

```
struct TestEditorView: View {
    
    @State var text = NSAttributedString(string: "")
    @State var selection: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                if let _ = selection {
                    ScrollView {
                        HStack {
                            TextView(text: $text)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The UITextView**

```
struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
 
    @Binding var text: NSAttributedString
 
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        
        textView.attributedText = TextFormatter.format(text.string)
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        return textView
    }
 
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.attributedText = TextFormatter.format(text.string)
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> TextViewCoordinator {
        TextViewCoordinator(text: $text)
    }
}

class TextViewCoordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
    
    @Binding private var text: NSAttributedString
    
    init(text: Binding<NSAttributedString>) {
        self._text = text
    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        text = TextFormatter.format(textView.attributedText.string)
    }
}
```

P.S. I do not believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836162/how-to-add-line-numbers-to-a-uitextview) applies because it is in objective-c and does not interface with SwiftUI.

Comment: if you control the line spacing of your UITExtView you can just draw line numbers next to it in the SwiftUI View

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution Mark?